# Some strange (or not) thing with mysql 'volume'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volume

Just create database service with docker-compose.yaml:

```
# another db service for test

version: '3.5'

networks:
  dockernet:
    driver: bridge

services:
  db:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.5.62
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
    volumes:
      - ./mysql_dir:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - dockernet
```

Next, adding directory 'mysql' in my ~:

```
docker:~/docker$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r--    1 futur    futur          674 Nov  5 04:35 docker-compose.yaml
drwxr-sr-x    2 futur    futur         4096 Nov  5 04:37 mysql_dir
```

I added my account to group 'docker':

```
docker:~/docker$ grep docker /etc/group
docker:x:101:futur
```

After up/down my docker-compose, i see strange changing permissions of my directory:

```
docker:~/docker$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r--    1 futur    futur          298 Nov  5 05:10 docker-compose.yaml
drwxr-sr-x    5 27       video         4096 Nov  5 05:11 mysql_dir
```

Why it became '27' and 'video'? What is that? Is that normal?

Such behavior prevents copying and moving directory 'mysql_dir' for me (user 'futur').

Should i use docker only from root user? Is there any way to use docker with avoid using root user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `docker exec <your_container> stat /var/lib/mysql` on your host, to check permissions of `/var/lib/mysql` folder **in the container**, then you'll see that its uid is `27` (user `mysql`) and gid is `27` (group `mysql`) :

```
  File: '/var/lib/mysql'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
...
Access: (0750/drwxr-x---)  Uid: (   27/   mysql)   Gid: (   27/   mysql)
...
```

When you mount a volume between your host and a container, Docker changes permissions of the mounted directory on your host according to what's inside the container (here `uid=27`, `gid=27`).

What you see from your host is then normal : `27` is because you don't have any user on your host with `uid=27`, and you see `video` group because this group have `gid=27` on your host (you can validate that by running `getent group video`).

You could change `mysql` uid and gid inside the container to match the ones on your host, but I strongly discourage you from doing that. Instead of mounting local directories, you would rather use [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#create-and-manage-volumes), if you want to make backup of your data for example.

Comment: Ok, so what should be the proper way? 
Should I create group and user with same id for mysql (on the _host_ machine)? 
Or maybe I must work with docker only through root user? Because creating _volume_ goes with root owner...

Comment: You can create a volume without being root (you belong to group `docker` as you have shown). Like I said in the answer, I do not recommend to modify your host users and groups to match containers users. What is your particular use case? Is there a reason that you want to have mysql data in a local directory on your host (easy to backup for example)?

Comment: Yes. But there is another strange thing -- although i added user to group docker, directory _/var/lib/docker_ have _drwx--x--x_ by default (no read rights except for owner -- _root_, and owner group for directory _root_ too). 
Maybe I installed docker package not correctly... 
My case is mediawiki+mysql+adminer container, and I want to keep mediawiki directory and database in my local store (backups, etc).

Comment: `root:root` owner and `drwx--x--x` permissions are totally normal for `/var/lib/docker`, you do not have to worry about that :) it contains internal files/directories used by Docker, that's why its access is restricted. But it does not prevent you to build images, create volumes, etc from your own user (in `docker` group). For creating volume backups easily, you can follow [this tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes).

Comment: kk thank you! // _I had to check main maunals before asking question_ :)